# SplitView app with master and detail view visible in both orientations

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I would like to have both master and detail views visible in landscape and portrait modes.

Like how the Settings app is implemented.

I do not find any samples for this. Appreciate your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt has done wonderful work see http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad source available at GitHub

Answer (score 2):

`UISplitViewController` doesn't support this, at least not in a documented way. Why not build your own custom split view?

Comment: If you don't want to use the ability to hide the master view in portrait the split view doesn't do anything you need. Ditch it completely and layout what you want from scratch. It won't take hardly any work to do.

Comment: Thanks guys.. Can you please give me some pointers as to how I can do this?

Do I simply create 2 table view controllers, and do all the work programmatically?

Also, how do I take care of orientation changes?